# Facebook Open Graph Image

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph

I had to restore a php page from an old version and now facebook debugging is not finding the og:image tag any more.
A share url is: https://maltishlanguage.com/dictionary/0603/

If I share debug the link on the LinkedIn post inspector, the og:image is shown correctly.

in the  tag, I have an og:image (http jpg URL) and a og:image:secure (https jpeg URL)

The Graph API Explorer gives a good image:

```js
{
  "url": "https://maltishlanguage.com/dictionary/0523/rude/1?s=s",
  "type": "website",
  "title": "Maltish - I am turning round in the nothing",
  "image": [
    {
      "url": "http://maltishlanguage.com/images/fbMaltishLanguageDictionary.jpg"
    }
  ],
  "description": "Maltish Dictionary entry from the Expression 'Qed indur fix-xejn '",
  "updated_time": "2022-07-21T05:24:04+0000"
}
```

Comment: Your example URL produces an error, _"Notice:  Undefined index: rudeLimit in /home/customer/www/maltishlanguage.com/public_html/dictionary.php on line 41"_ The Facebook scraper can be quite picky about HTML code that was invalidated by such error messages being output into the source.

Comment: Hi @CBroe, could you kindly let me know how you got the notice and error, as it does not show in the page source and the Facebook see what Facebook see gives me an error saying 'Oops
Something went wrong. We're working on getting it fixed as soon as we can.'

Comment: It looks like it only shows the notice if there are no existing cookies (but that will always be the case for the Facebook scraper.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Cbroe solved the issue for me, many thanks and sorry i did not understand you initially, but I just checked by setting Google into cookieless mode which showed the error where I had a session check, but in the else I was still tryiong toe read the session if not set and it was thoring the error @CBroe mentioned!

Solved and it's working now :)

So issue was that a PHP error was being written to the outpu HTML in the HEAD tag.